# fig.autofmt_xdate() supresses ax.set_position()

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm drawing plots using matplotlib.
I want to place legends outside the plot and therefore I use ax.set_position() to shrink the plot width. 
However, this only works when I omit fig.autofmt_xdate()
to to have 45 degree rotated x labels (timestamps). 
Is there a way to do both? Here is a code example.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,13))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=1, height_ratios=[3,1,1])
for i in xrange (0,3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i])
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.5, box.height])    
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
#fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fig.autofmt_xdate()` automatically calls `subplot_adjust()` which messes up your layout.

The solution is simple: just perform the same steps that `fig.autofmt_xdate()` does, but by hand.

```
from matplotlib import gridspec   
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,13))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=3, ncols=1, height_ratios=[3,1,1])
for i in xrange (0,3):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[i])
    ax.scatter(np.random.random((10)),np.random.random((10)), label='scatter %d'%(i))
    box = ax.get_position()
    ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.5, box.height])    
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
#fig.autofmt_xdate()
for ax in fig.get_axes():
    if ax.is_last_row():
        for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
            label.set_ha('right')
            label.set_rotation(30.)
    else:
        for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
            label.set_visible(False)
        ax.set_xlabel('')
plt.show()
```